# How can I use SoapExtensionReflector in WCF?

Tags: wcf

I'm trying to change wsdl in wcf web service. I found this article http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2005/11/16/493496.aspx but unfortunately I can't make it work.

It's web config

```
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>

    <services>
      <service name="Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples.CalculatorService" behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceTypeBehaviors" >
        <endpoint contract="Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples.ICalculator" binding="mexHttpBinding" address="mex" />
      </service>
    </services>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MyServiceTypeBehaviors" >
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

  </system.serviceModel>

  <system.web>
    <webServices>
      <soapExtensionReflectorTypes>
        <add type="Msdn.Web.Services.Samples.HttpsReflector, App_Code"/>
      </soapExtensionReflectorTypes>
    </webServices>
  </system.web>

</configuration>
```

Additional link http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms733766.aspx